# What are my options when it comes to uploading a excel sheet to a table in a database

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I am working on a little project of mine and I came to the conclusion that being able to automatically upload a excel sheet to my database would be very, very useful, the table itself would be a User table with Id, name and title.

I ask because I am still new to programming in general and I don't want to do something overly complicated, just a small popUp with a upload input with the type of file restricted to only the one I would use and for the file to be uploaded and entered into the database.

I would most likely keep using Wamp server for this if it makes any difference. Also the code to achieve this should be either HTML, JS PHP or a combination of those seeing that I don't really know ANYTHING yet of any other language.

I was told that one way would be to export excel sheets to CSV (Comma Separated Value?) and then upload it that way. But I don't really know how start about that.

Any help or suggestions would be great. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Ehh.  Access always works well enough for me, for one-time jobs.

Comment: @cHao Access? Well it wouldn't exactly be one time, more like uploading to update each couple of months depending, and I am not talking about massive sized files either

Comment: The problem is that the file upload and any function to make it work must be inside php/js/html files. Not a external software

Comment: There are Excel readers for PHP, if it simply must be PHP.  Check out Google.

Comment: @panofish I did!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275636/upload-csv-into-database-using-php